# perl: How to I count multiple values in hash into a new hash?

Tags: perl

My current hash:

```
%hash = (
  "foo",
   [
     "apple",
     "orange",
     "apple",
     "apple"
  ],
  "bob",
  [
    "apple",
    "orange",
  ],
);
```

How do I obtain this output?

```
%hash2 = (
  apple  => 4,
  orange => 2,
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my %counts;
for (values(%hash)) {  # Iterate over the values of the hash, the references to the arrays.
   for (@$_) {         # Iterate over the values of the referenced array.
      ++$counts{$_};
   }
}
```

or

```
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for map @$_, values %hash;
```

Comment: Name the iterator variable in for loops.

Comment: Replacing one meaningless name with another doesn't help.

Comment: That's why you should choose meaningful names for your variables and functions.